# Opencart MultiMerch seller profile edit

Tags: opencart2.x, opencart-module

When I'm going to edit the seller account I'm getting the following error in opencart 2.0.3.1 and also getting 2 multiseller icons in the admin panel.

[image]

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

```
OK

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Page Not Found!</title>
<base href="http://localhost/oc2.3/admin/" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="view/javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="view/javascript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="view/javascript/bootstrap/opencart/opencart.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="view/javascript/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="view/javascript/summernote/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="view/javascript/summernote/summernote.js"></script>
<script src="view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<link type="text/css" href="view/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<script src="view/javascript/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

                                <script type="text/javascript"> if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}}; var msGlobals = { config_limit_admin: '20', config_language: 'view/javascript/multimerch/datatables/lang/en.lng' }; </script>


                                <script type="text/javascript"> if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}}; var msGlobals = { config_limit_admin: '20', config_language: 'view/javascript/multimerch/datatables/lang/en.lng' }; </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<header id="header" class="navbar navbar-static-top">
  <div class="navbar-header">
        <a type="button" id="button-menu" class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-indent fa-lg"></i></a>
        <a href="http://localhost/oc2.3/admin/index.php?route=common/dashboard&amp;token=c77818da8112eaa8c6da6c6b8197f498" class="navbar-brand"><img src="view/image/logo.png" alt="OpenCart" title="OpenCart" /></a></div>
    <ul class="nav pull-right">
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="label label-danger pull-left">1</span> <i class="fa fa-bell fa-lg"></i></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right alerts-dropdown">
        <li class="dropdown-header">Orders</li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/oc2.3/admin/index.php?route=sale/order&amp;token=c77818da8112eaa8c6da6c6b8197f498&amp;filter_order_status=2" style="display: block; overflow: auto;"><span class="label label-warning pull-right">0</span>Pending</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/oc2.3/admin/index.php?route=sale/order&amp;token=c77818da8112eaa8c6da6c6b8197f498&amp;filter_order_status=5"><span class="label label-success pull-right">0</span>Completed</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/oc2.3/admin/index.php?route=sale/return&amp;token=c77818da8112eaa8c6da6c6b8197f498"><span class="label label-danger pull-right">0</span>Returns</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="dropdown-header">Customers</li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/oc2.3/admin/index.php?route=report/customer_online&amp;token=c77818da8112eaa8c6da6c6b8197f498"><span class="label label-success pull-right">0</span>Customers Online</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/oc2.3/admin/index.php?route=sale/customer&amp;token=c77818da8112eaa8c6da6c6b8197f498&amp;filter_approved=0"><span class="label label-danger pull-right">0</span>Pending approval</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="dropdown-header">Products</li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/oc2.3/admin/index.php?route=catalog/product&amp;token=c77818da8112eaa8c6da6c6b8197f498&amp;filter_quantity=0"><span class="label label-danger pull-right">1</span>Out of stock</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/oc2.3/admin/index.php?route=catalog/review&amp;token=c77818da8112eaa8c6da6c6b8197f498&amp;filter_status=0"><span class="label label-danger pull-right">0</span>Reviews</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="dropdown-header">Affiliates</li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/oc2.3/admin/index.php?route=marketing/affiliate&amp;token=c77818da8112eaa8c6da6c6b8197f498&amp;filter_approved=1"><span class="label label-danger pull-right">0</span>Pending approval</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-life-ring fa-lg"></i></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <li class="dropdown-header">Stores <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/oc2.3/" target="_blank">Tailors &amp; Desginers</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="dropdown-header">Help <i class="fa fa-life-ring"></i></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.opencart.com" target="_blank">Homepage</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://docs.opencart.com" target="_blank">Documentation</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://forum.opencart.com" target="_blank">Support Forum</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/oc2.3/admin/index.php?route=common/logout&amp;token=c77818da8112eaa8c6da6c6b8197f498"><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">Logout</span> <i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-lg"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
  </header>         
<nav id="column-left"><div id="profile">
  <div><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="http://localhost/oc2.3/image/cache/no_image-45x45.png" alt="John Doe" title="admin" class="img-circle" /></a></div>
  <div>
    <h4>John Doe</h4>
    <small>Administrator</small></div>
</div>
<ul id="menu">
  <li id="dashboard"><a href="http://localhost/oc2.3/admin/index.php?route=common/dashboard&amp;token=c77818da8112eaa8c6da6c6b8197f498"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
  <li id="catalog"><a class="parent"><i class="fa fa-tags fa-fw"></i> <span>Catalog</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://localhost/oc2.3/admin/index.php?route=catalog/category&amp;token=c77818da8112eaa8c6da6c6b8197f498">Categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://localhost/oc2.3/admin/index.php?route=catalog/product&amp;token=c77818da8112eaa8c6da6c6b8197f498">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://localhost/oc2.3/admin/index.php?route=catalog/recurring&amp;token=c77818da8112eaa8c6da6c6b8197f498">Recurring Profiles</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://localhost/oc2.3/admin/index.php?route=catalog/filter&amp;token=c77818da8112eaa8c6da6c6b8197f498">Filters</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a broken MultiMerch and/or vQmod installation (hence the duplicates and missing language variables).

I would suggest you to update your MultiMerch and vQmod to the latest versions available on GitHub.

If you're using OpenCart 2.0.3.1, you will also need to remove the vqmod/xml/multimerch_oc21x_controllerfix.xml file. It is only needed for OpenCart 2.1.x.

That will fix this.

Answer (score -1):

For the Admin and the front-end error I think you should check your `vqmod` file that's where the error is coming from or you can try a new installation.